# Does it matter if I generate questions using AI?

Tags: discussion

I asked for a [policy regarding AI-use in the site](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/should-we-define-an-esse-ai-use-policy), but nobody is saying anything. I guess we don't have a trouble, so nobody wonders.

[I generated a question title using GPT-4 and posted it](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25079/how-do-the-characteristics-of-pleistocene-loess-deposits-provide-insights-into-t), as we have no policy.

We have 1.6 questions/day in the site, wich is a low number of questions.

I have free time in my job in administration and I can post 1 daily question generated by this system to reach 2.5 questions/day if this is not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is a problem.  We don't want a ChatGPT site.
See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

I think we should adopt the same policy here on ES SE.

Comment: Ok, I won't post more. I asked the bot to generate a not too much broad question, but the questions it generate are very broad.

Answer (score 3):

There's long been a recommendation on SE sites that users only post questions that they genuinely want the answer to.  See https://stackexchange.com/tour:

> Ask about...
>
> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

Using LLMs to generate questions purely for the purpose of increasing the amount of content on this site doesn't pass this test.  I also suspect that users would be less likely to answer a question that they felt was generated by an AI because it gives a weaker sense that they're helping someone.  That might increase the Q count on the site, but it would worsen the Q:A ratio.

A potential legitimate use case is where someone uses an LLM to rephrase a genuine question, particularly when English isn't their first language.  A blanket ban on the use of LLMs as a tool might be an exclusionary policy, given that this currently doesn't appear to be a problem on ES.SE.

A more nuanced policy would be based around banning problem uses (e.g., content farming) and/or permitting narrow uses (e.g., improving your own question).  It would be harder to police, but more equitable.